# ¿Cómo dar a un rol todos los permisos en discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy intentando hacer un comando con un bot con discord.py que dé a un rol ya creado todos los permisos que se le pueden dar a un rol (leer, escribir, hablar, escuchar, borrar, administrador, ect). Me he imaginado que sería algo como esto:

```
await guild.set_role(rolename, all=True)
```

Comment: Lo que sale en el código

Comment: ¿ Podrías explicar un poco mas lo que buscas ?

Comment: Proporcionas muy poco contexto para que alguien te pueda ayudar. Ofrecer una recompensa no es suficiente. ¿Qué es el objeto `guild`?  De hecho ninguna de las clases de discordpy implementa `set_role()` así que imagino que el código que has pegado es un "deseo" de cómo te gustaría a ti que fuese la  API, más que una investigación que hayas realizado en la documentación.

Comment: Más que deseo, parece que tiene una concepción errónea de en qué consiste el desarrollo de software, creo que por lo mismo le damos la impresión de ser adivinos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacer exactamente lo que deseas mediante el siguiente código:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('NOMBRE_DEL_ROL_QUE_PUEDE_EJECUTAR_EL_COMANDO')
async def give_all_permissions(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()     #Esto elimina el mensaje automáticamente (su uso es opcional)
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:     #Aquí iteramos sobre todos los roles del servidor
        if role.name == "NOMBRE_DEL_ROL_A_MODIFICAR":     #Seleccionamos el rol que deseamos modificar
            await role.edit(reason=None, permissions=Permissions().all())     #Añadimos todos los permisos a ese rol
            return
```